# VueJS: render new component after click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

I'd like to render new component in vue.js as if it's new page.

I'm trying to do it with something called "dynamic component"

**parent**: Post.vue
**child**: Detail.vue

so, if one of the posts is clicked, Post is off and Detail is on.

The thing is I have to send clicked post's id to the Detail.

Here's some of my code.

**Post.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="loading">
      loading...
    </div>
    <div v-else class="container">
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(post, index) in filteredPosts" v-bind:key="post.no">
            <section class="post__main">
              <div @click..?? class="main__title">{{post.title}}</div>
            </section>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    created() {
      axios.get(this.url, {
        params: {
          page: this.page,
          ord: this.ord,
          category: []
        }
      }).then(res => {
        this.posts = res.data.list;
        this.loading = false;
        this.page++;
      });
```

**Detail.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{contents}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    name: 'Datail',
    data() {
        return {
            req_no: null,
            contents: {}
        }
    },
    created() {
      axios.get(url, {
        params: {
          req_no: this.req_no
        }
      }).then(res => {
          this.contents = this.res.data
      });
    }
}
</script>
```

I feel like I can do it with `props` and `v-if`.
Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: 'as if it's new page.' You might want to look into vue-router

Comment: @Frank I've looked through it, but as I have to get the data with Ajax, it seems not applicable.

Comment: That's not an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a post is clicked, pass post id to the click handler. In the click handler, route to detail.vue passing post id as route param.

like below:

```
  <li v-for="(post, index) in filteredPosts" v-bind:key="post.no">
      <section class="post__main">
          <div @click="onPostClick(post.id)" class="main__title">{{post.title}}</div>
      </section>
  </li>
```

And in your click handler:

```
 onPostClick(id: number) {
        this.$router.push({
            name: 'details',
            params: {
                id
            }
        });
    }
```

This will work provided you set up vue router correctly in your app and have a valid route for details.

You can access the post id in details component as follows:

```
created() {
    this.postId = this.$route.params.id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at the `<component>` which takes a prop `:to` and renders a component, this is good for something like tabs where you are rendering different component from a the same general location on the page without reloading the whole page. See here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html
This seems to be a very good use case for you, just pass into the `component` the props you need.